# Pointer changing automatically after function call for simple linkedlist C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am a beginner in C++, I was implementing simple linked list in C++. While I try to add a second element to list, the pointer for next element in the head is changing

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList ll;
    string test;
    test="we";
    ll.add("we");
    ll.add("are");
    cout << "ok working" << endl;
    return 0;
}

class LinkedList
{
    public:
        LinkedList();
        void add(string data);
    protected:
    private:
        class node{
        private:
            string data;
        public:
            node *next;
            node(string data,node *next);
            node(string data);
            node();
        };

        node *head;
};

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head=NULL;
    cout<<"ok";
}


void LinkedList::add(string data){
    if(!head){
        node tmphead(data,NULL);
        this->head=&tmphead;
    }else{
        node *temp;
        temp=head;
        while(temp->next){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        node newnode(data);
        temp->next=&newnode;
    }
}
LinkedList::node::node(string data,node *next){
    LinkedList::node::data=data;
    LinkedList::node::next=next;
cout<<"New node created with : "+data<< endl;

}
LinkedList::node::node(){
    LinkedList::node::data="";
    LinkedList::node::next=NULL;
    //LinkedList::node::
//this->data="";
//this->next=NULL;
}
LinkedList::node::node(string data){
LinkedList::node::data=data;
LinkedList::node::next=NULL;
}
```

**when adding "we", head-> next is 0x0. Once the control goes to the add function again for "are", the head->next is 0x3. It is getting changes automatically.**

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `node tmphead(data,NULL); this->head=&tmphead;` is taking the address of a local object, which ceases to exist at the end of that scope. Dereferencing `this->head` would be undefined behavior beyond that point.

Comment: Learn to use the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and its watchpoints

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think debugger is why OP knows that `head->next` changed to what it did.

Comment: But watchpoints give the exact point where it did change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning pointer to local variable to head. That's really bad.

```
if(!head){
    node tmphead(data,NULL);
    this->head=&tmphead;
} // After this bracket, tmphead was dealocated
```

When you do this kinda stuff, anything can happen since you're accessing memory that is not allocated to you any more.

Same here:

```
    node newnode(data);
    temp->next=&newnode;
    // after function exits, `temp->next` points to deallocated memory
```

Instead, use `new` in both cases:

```
void LinkedList::add(string data){
    if(!head){
        this->head = new node(data, nullptr);
    }else{
        node* temp;
        temp=head;
        while(temp->next){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new node(data);
    }
}
```

Also, remember to create some way to `delete` everything you created using `new`.

For example:

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
    delete head;
}
node::~node() {
    // WARNING: this is recursive
    // that's not bad but it's important to be aware of it
    if(next != nullptr)
        delete next;
}
```

You don't need to delete the `string data` - it's destructor is called automatically when `node` is deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. But I'll just go ahead and recommend you google stuff like `constructor destructor c++ pointers tutorial`. The explanation of those things does not fit in comment boxes really. Try to read something about it and if you're lost, ask another question, somebody will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are building a dynamic structure without using dynamic memory. The lifetime of the variables tmphead and newnode is limited to the add() call, so their addresses become invalid on exit. Please review new and delete sections in some tutorial

Comment: Suggestion: replace "the heap memory" with "dynamic memory". Not only is it more technically correct, but it aligns with "dynamic structure" a  few words earlier for a more memorable sentence.